# Retrieve image from firebase storage to show on tableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I just need help I building Instagram-clone with firebase and I have an issue whit post feed I can't Retrieve image from firebase storage to show on tableView cell can you help me, please :(

import UIKit

import FirebaseAuth

import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate  {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var posts = [Post]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.dataSource = self
    loadposts()

 //   var post = Post(captiontxt: "test", photoUrlString: "urll")
 //   print(post.caption)
 //   print(post.photoUrl)

}

func loadposts() {
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.childAdded){ (snapshot: DataSnapshot)in
        print(Thread.isMainThread)
          if let dict = snapshot.value  as? [String: Any]{
            let captiontxt = dict["caption"] as! String
            let photoUrlString = dict["photoUrl"] as! String
           let post = Post(captiontxt: captiontxt, photoUrlString: photoUrlString )
            self.posts.append(post)
            print(self.posts)
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }catch let logoutErrorr{
        print(logoutErrorr)
    }
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
    let signinVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SigninViewController")
    self.present(signinVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

}
extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count

```
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imagecell", for: indexPath) as! PostCellTableViewCell
   cell.captionLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption
    cell.postimage.image =  posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl
   // print(cell.captionLabel.text)
   // print(cell.daysLabel.text)


    return cell
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

---

import Foundation
class Post {
    var caption: String
    var photoUrl: String

```
init(captiontxt: String, photoUrlString: String) {
    caption = captiontxt
    photoUrl = photoUrlString

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imagecell", for: indexPath) as! PostCellTableViewCell

    cell.postimage.image = nil

    cell.tag += 1
    let tag = cell.tag

    cell.captionLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption

    let photoUrl = posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl

    getImage(url: photoUrl) { photo in
        if photo != nil {
            if cell.tag == tag {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.postimage.image = photo
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func getImage(url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            completion(UIImage(data: data!))
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: XCode 9 has a new runtime Main Thread Checker that detects call to UIKit from a background thread and generate warnings. Its meant to generate warnings and not crash the app, but you can try disabling Main Thread Checker for your test target or ignore it for current case (because in previous Xcode versions it wasn't a error). Main Thread Checker finds all code that connects with views in background thread and show errors, but in this case cell.tag doesn't give any bad consequences, so don't worry about that)

Comment: If you want to disable Main Thread Checker do this: select target -> edit scheme  -> test -> Diagnostics -> uncheck  Main Thread Checker

Comment: the problem is not Main Thread Checker the project run fine but the layout is not running like it should

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the layout ? On screenshot i see 3 rows and yes it looks strange, but this is problem of table settings and PostCellTableViewCell layout.

Comment: my code just implements the right logic of retrieving images and setting image property of cell.postimage. But the appearance of postimage is determined in PostCellTableViewCel.

Comment: ok thanks ( yakovlevvl ) just another question if I want to retrieve user image I just do it the same way?

Comment: yes, and also you can create a dictionary [photoUrl : photo] and when you get photo for url, you add this pair to dictionary. Something like cache (to save traffic). And you have to put code just before getImage(url: photoUrl) that check you have photo for this url or not. If not, run getImage(url: photoUrl).